# How to disable icicles integration with helm?

Tags: key-bindings, helm, icicles

Long time ago I updated Helm and it replaced normal Icicles behaviour for choosing files.

I had icicles bound to `C-x C-f`:

```
C-x C-f runs the command icicle-file, which is an interactive Lisp
function in `icicles-cmd1.el'
```

But after the Helm update Emacs began to open `helm-find-file` over-designed dialog instead of normal behaviour. The user experienced dropped hereafter.

Today my patience has run out and I determined to break Helm and Icicles integration. Could you advise me from which side should I begin my quest?

Answer (score 1):

[Icicles](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles) does not do anything to "integrate with" Helm. Perhaps Helm does something to "integrate with" Icicles, but I doubt it.

More likely is that you loaded some other library (perhaps a Helm add-on someone wrote) that grabs some of the key bindings that Icicles uses by default.

If the only problem you have is *key bindings* then my suggestion would be to customize the bindings the way you like.

The place to start is `C-h k` followed by the key you're interested in. That should tell you what command it is bound to, and what library/file it is defined in. If it does not tell you the file but it tells you only that the key is bound to command `some-helmish-whatever` then search (e.g. `M-x grep`) the source code of the libraries you use, to find out where it is defined, where it is bound to the key, and in what keymap it is bound to that key. You can then just unbind it from that keymap, if you want (i.e., bind it to `nil` in that map).

If you don't easily find out which code is grabbing the Icicles bindings you want Icicles to have, or you don't want to try that, then an alternative is to make Icicles use different key bindings.

That is  easy to do. There are Icicles user options for customizing each group of Icicles default keybindings. The Icicles doc, section [Customizing Key Bindings](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Customizing_Key_Bindings) tells you all about this.

If it is a top-level key that you're interested in, such as `C-x C-f`, then the option to customize is **`icicle-top-level-key-bindings`**.  Just bind some other key to the command (`icicle-file`) that Icicles binds by default to `C-x C-f`.

Looking at the option value you can see that by default Icicles *remaps* vanilla Emacs command `find-file` to Icicles command `icicle-file`.  In file `icicles-opt.el` you'll see "`C-x C-f'" as a comment next to the line that does that.

So in this case, instead of Icicles explicitly binding (by default) key `C-x C-f` to `icicle-file`, it instead *remaps all keys bound to command `find-file`* to `icicle-file` (while in Icicle mode).

If some other library (Helm or whatever) itself remaps `find-file` first then there will be no keys bound to it for Icicles to remap.  In that case, you can try changing the order of invocation, invoking `icy-mode` before the other (e.g. Helm) mode. Or you can try the other way around.

But a simple alternative is to just add some other binding to `icicle-top-level-bindings`, to use some key other than `C-x C-f` for `icicle-file`.

Comment: > The place to start is C-h k followed by the key you're interested in

That is exactly what I have done at the first place. And I put the output in the question. "C-x C-f runs the command icicle-file"

Comment: You say that you had that originally, but after you updated Helm that key instead invokes `helm-find-file` (so presumably `C-h k` says `help-find-file`). Now you can look for the library that defines  `helm-find-file` etc. (if `C-h k` doesn't tell you). Without more info I can't offer more help, I think. Maybe provide a step-by-step recipe, if you are doing something more then just trying `C-x C-f` at top level.

Comment: That is what appointed currently to `C-x C-f`. It runs `icicle-file`. But it displays helm instead of normal choices. So it is some kind of integration: I call `icicle-file` and get helm after that, so icicles now for some reason calls helm to provide file choices

Comment: Dunno. Take a look at the code for `helm-find-file` (or whatever helmish function is actually doing the displaying). Icicles is not calling it, but it might well have gotten itself invoked. Do `M-x debug-on-entry helm-find-file`, and when it comes up in the debugger you'll likely see how it was invoked. Perhaps it advises some display function, coopting it. Or perhaps someone here familiar with it will offer a suggestion.

Comment: BTW, googling a bit suggests that the Helm function is `helm-find-files`, not `helm-find-file`. If you're seeing the latter then perhaps it's not from Helm itself. If you're really seeing the former the that's what to `debug-on-entry`, to see how it is being invoked.